# PHPStorm Symfony/Twig ignore a getter from entity

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpstorm

I'm using the last PhpStorm version with Symfony plugin and its dependencies and got some issue for Twig entity method completion.

This is my `User` entity (working well)

```php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use App\Entity\UserInterface as BaseInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Adresse mail déjà utilisée")
 */
class User implements BaseInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profil", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $profil;

    // ...
    // setters and getters auto-generated
}
```

And there is my Controller action:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/user", name="user_")
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED")
 */
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/profil", name="profil")
     */
    public function profil()
    {
        // I tried to load it from doctrine repository and also tried to add @var Profil comment
        $user = $this->getUser();

        return $this->render('security/user/profil.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And finally my template:

```
{% block user_content %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-hover tabless">
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td>{{ user.profil.username }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date Inscription</td>
                    <td>{{ user.profil.createdAt | date('d/m/Y') }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dernière Modification</td>
                    <td>{{ user.profil.updatedAt | date('d/m/Y') }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Roles</td>
                    <td>
                        {% for role in user.roles %}
                            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-">{{ role|trans }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>{{ user.profil.description }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My issue is that in the twig template, PhpStorm does not find profile getter from user variable. I tried to see user variable reference, and it sends me to the Symfony `UserInterface`, not mine, that's why I tried to make my own with the `getProfil()` function.

The strangest thing is that if I do `{{ app.user.profil }}` it totally work and autocomplete it.

Comment: PhpStorm's Twig support cannot pick up variables from your Symfony controllers (as it does not provide own framework integration) -- that's what extra Twig support from Symfony plugin does (or should be doing). **In any case:** Symfony plugin supports typehinting (inline `@var` PHPDoc comments) in Twig files -- please try adding such typehint comment in your .twig file for your `user` variable: https://symfony2-plugin.espend.de/languages/twig/index.html#phptypes

Answer (score 0):

Just add annotation in the controller

```
   use App\Entity\User;


   /** @var User $user */
   $user = $this->getUser();
```

Comment: I put a comment in my code to explain that I already tested that. So, no it's not making it work.

Comment: did you import th user Class with "use" ?

Comment: Yep, i also tried to put a comment in the twig template

Comment: are you sure that the plugin symfony is enabled for the current project ?